# Use "this" in Runnable inside Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, handler

In my `onResume()` I'm running a new Handler which runs the following line of code:

```
adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feed);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, when I move this code into the Handler, the `this` inside the first line becomes disallowed because obviously it's inside a runnable, as shown here:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        adapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feed);
        list.setAdapter(adapter); 
    } 
}, 500);
```

Now, my question is how I access the Fragment I'm in without having to create a method/variable storing the current Fragment?

I got around the issue by doing the following:

```
private FeedListActivity myInstance(){
    return this;
}
```

And changing `this` to `myInstance()`, but it seems a bad way of doing it. Same with creating a new variable to store the Fragment. Is there a way I can call the Fragment I'm running from?

Perhaps this will make it clear what I want to do:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        adapter = new FeedListAdapter(getFragment(), feed);
        list.setAdapter(adapter); 
    } 
}, 500);
```

All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use an inner class, it implicitly has reference to outer class. You can use syntax: `FeedListActivity.this` inside an inner class.

Comment: Have absolutely no idea why I didn't do this in the first place. Late night oversights I think! (also, can't accept for 8 minutes)